# What is the difference between a focus mark and an actor's mark?

Tags: cinematography, blocking

As I understand it, camera men generally discriminate between a "focus mark" and an actor's mark or "land". Is the idea that a land is just where the talent goes when they are not the subject, but a focus mark is where they go when they are the subject?

For example, if the lead is red and there is a red mark put down, then why would we need a separate pink mark for focus? Why not just focus on the lands?

Comment: http://www.theblackandblue.com/2011/04/25/focus-measurements/

Comment: That's a very good link, @Paulie_D - but you must read the comments underneath for some good real world tips too. Most of the guys I see measure 'soft' to the nose not the eyes if they know their DoF is going to be shallow - it's a good 'escape plan'.

Comment: Huh? I thought the focus mark was the mark **on the lens** that tells the focus puller where to stop. Actor's marks are on the floor, where the *actor* stops. Regardless, this seems like it's off topic here but should be on topic on [video.se].

Comment: @Catija Here I am talking about lands, which are usually colored tape on the set showing where the actor is supposed to step. A "focus mark" is a type of land that usually has its own color, and I want to know why that is.

Comment: Can you show some example of this in actual use?

Comment: @Tyler Durden Focus mark is another word for focus pulling isn't it?

Comment: I'm with @Catija on this... I've seen a million marks dropped for actors & a million bits of random coloured tape dropped by the focus puller for a long follow shot; but I've never seen anyone bother to co-ordinate the colour scheme. It's a lot more organic than the question would seem to suggest. All marks are lifted if the ground is in shot, of course & then everybody is guessing - but these are professional guessers. I've also worked on fast turnover stuff where you'd be looked at oddly if you asked for a mark - they expect you to get it right by take two.